# envoyproxy listener filter for ssh traffic

Tags: envoyproxy

Is there any filters available for listeners in envoy proxy to send the traffic to a seperate cluster,

I have similar config for haproxy

```
# 5353482d322e30 is the binary representation of the string 'SSH-2.0'
    acl client_attempts_ssh payload(0,7) -m bin 5353482d322e30
```

```
    - filter_chain_match:
        destination_port: 22
```

Tried this but now working